# Calling C# COM DLL from C++

Tags: c#, c++, com

The C++ code is as follows

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <Windows.h>
#import "C:\shreyas\Documents\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\bin\Debug\ConsoleApplication1.tlb" no_namespace

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

    CoInitialize(NULL);
    IMyClassPtr obj;

    //iProgramPtr obj;
    obj.CreateInstance(__uuidof(MyClass));
    printf("value: %d",obj->display());
    CoUninitialize();
    getchar();

    return 0;
}
```

The C# code is as follows

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace demo
{
    [ComVisible(true)]
    public interface IMyClass
    {
        int display();
    }


    [ComVisible(true)]
    [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
    class MyClass : IMyClass
    {
        public int display()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello");
            return 10;
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to call the C# display function from C++ code. I have done the required settings in C# project properties. In the code `obj.CreateInstance(__uuid(MyClass));` the `MyClass` is giving an error as an undefined identifier.

Comment: Have a look in the generate tlh file (created by the `#import`) for the GUID associated with `MyClass`, it may be in a namespace or have some additional annotations.

Comment: on the C++ side you must release `obj` pointer before calling `CoUninitialize`

Comment: You should use `[Guid]` to explicitly specify the ids for the class and the interface otherwise they may be regenerated on next build and you'll have to recompile your client program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do pay attention to the build warning you get when you compile ConsoleApplication1:

> warning MSB3214: "C:...\ConsoleApplication1\bin\Debug\ConsoleApplication1.dll" does not contain any types that can be registered for COM Interop.

That's not good of course.  Also something you see with you look at the .tlb file with Oleview.exe's View + Typelib command.  Or open the .tlh file that the #import directive generates with a text editor, find it back in the C++ project's Debug directory.  You'll see that MyClass is completely missing, thus the compile error.

That is because of:

```
   class MyClass : IMyClass
```

You forgot to declare it `public`.  Required.